# Lindeberg's Condition is not necessary

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_n^k$ be Triangular Array ($k\leq n$) of independent mean $0$ random variables.
Suppose $\sum_k^n \text{Var}(X_n^k) = 1$.

> **Lindeberg's Condition** 
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_k^n E({X_n^k}^2;|X_n^k| > \epsilon) = 0 \quad\text{implies}\quad \sum_k^n X_n^k \Rightarrow_D N(0,1)
> \end{equation}

**Question** Show that Lindeberg's Condition is not necessary.

Only example that I was able to write down is $X_1 = N(0,1)$ and $X_2\equiv 0, X_3\equiv 0 ,\dots$.
Is there an example of non-degenerate sequence of random variables which does not satisfy Lindeberg's Condition but still converge in distribution to normal distribution?

It might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I think just taking any series $a_i$ that sums up to 1 and looking at normals $X_i = N (0, a_i)$ will do (and you should be able to show that via characteristic functions) (for finite, you can just say that sum of finite normals is still normal (again, by chf))